# AngularJS ui.router change page and go to specific section

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use the AngularJS `ui.router` in my application. For a new use case I want to change the view from `index.html` to my partialview options.html. My `options.html` has different sections.

The routing between the different views is working correctly, but I want to change the view and go directly to the `section` on this view.

Means from `resources/html/index.html` to `resources/html/index.html#/options` with a specific section.

I have a dropdown-menu with different `ui-sref` (some for tests) and there I want to call the view and section.

**Dropdown Menu in index.html**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a> //works fine
    <a ui-sref="options">Optionen</a> //works fine
    <a ui-sref="options" scroll-to="option1">option1</a> //here should be the call of the view and section 
    </li>
</ul>
```

**options.html with some sections**

```
<section id="option1">
  <div class="page-header">
   <h1>option1</h1>
   </div>
</section>
...
<section id="option2">
  <div class="page-header">
   <h1>option2</h1>
   </div>
</section>
```

**app.js**

```
App.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url : '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home/homeLayout.html'
        })
                .state('options', {
            url : '/options',
            templateUrl: 'options/options.html'
        });
}]);
```

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

If I hit the URL `resources/html/index.html#/options#option2` directly in the browser, I come to the options page and to the correct section. But this is what I dont want.

Comment: Use ui-sref="options" instead of ui-sref=".options" without dot. This should fix your problem.

Comment: This makes no diffrent in my case. I come to the options-page but not directy to the section I want. Any other suggestions?

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: Why you can't use two different pages for your two sections

Comment: Because I want one `options page` where different section are descripted. It should work similar like [bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) page (directives dropdown). In my application it will work if I am already on my options page. But I want to do it if I am not on the options page. Its like `Index.html -> options.html -> specific section`