# Angular - ui-router How to go to specific portion of a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to pass variable to a link in Ui-router.

```
<a ui-sref="Category({ SCID: sc.scid })" ui-sref-active="active" >{{ sc.scname }}</a>
```

and handle then in routing.

```
.state('Category', {
    templateUrl: "templates/Products.html",
    url: '/Category/:SCID/',
    controller: 'ProductsController as pc'
})
```

Now i want to go to specific portion of that page. say section starts with id=123.

```
<section id="123"> reach here directly on clicking link</section>
```

This question has been asked here by some other user also. [AngularJS ui.router change page and go to specific section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305078/angularjs-ui-router-change-page-and-go-to-specific-section)

But that don't have any answer.

Can somebody help me what change i need to make in URL and .state.

Comment: are you using `ui-router`?

Comment: @Razvan yes... I am using ui-router not ngRoute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [`$anchorScroll()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Basically, what you need to do is to set your routes as usual, passing the scroll param like:

```
url: '/first/:scrollTo',
```

and just add the following, injecting `$anchorScroll` and it will scroll you to any element with the id found in `$location.hash()`

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $stateParams, $timeout) { 
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    $timeout(function() { 
      $location.hash($stateParams.scrollTo);
      $anchorScroll()
    }, 100)
  });
})
```

Then, in your html, the links should look like:

```
<a href ui-sref="first({scrollTo: 'foo'})">First / Foo</a>
```

#### Here is a [<kbd>plunker</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/gAK2thwsEVE0x083tFJf?p=preview)

---

Alternatively, you can create an `onEnter:` function in your state to mange this:

```
.state('first', {
  url: '/first/:scrollTo',  
  controller: 'FirstCtrl', 
  templateUrl: 'first.html',
  onEnter: function ($location, $stateParams, $anchorScroll, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() { 
      $location.hash($stateParams.scrollTo);
      $anchorScroll()
    }, 100)
  }
})
```

Keeping things simpler in the state:

```
.state('first', {
  url: '/first/:scrollTo',  
  controller: 'FirstCtrl', 
  templateUrl: 'first.html',
  onEnter: scrollTo
})
```

```
var scrollTo = function() {
  function ($location, $stateParams, $anchorScroll, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() { 
      $location.hash($stateParams.scrollTo);
      $anchorScroll()
    }, 100)
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its working perfectly fine. If you know, can you share some link for adding smooth animation while scrolling.

Comment: Just one thing, now i cant access the page with out adding an `/` at the end, i have to write in the url: `example.com/first/`, any idea how to remove that?

Comment: @FireBrand thats because of UI-Router's, `strictMode` URL filtering. You can disable it by injecting `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider` in your app run function and set it as `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)`

Comment: @RazvanBalosin trying to inject the provider as you mentioned throws an injector error

Comment: Good answer, a slight improvement:
`$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + $stateParams.scrollTo).offset().top }, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to scroll to that section when you get to that specific page.

You can use the [angular-scroll](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll) directive for that purpose.

You can find the *sectionId* in the controller with `$scope.sectionId = $stateParams['SCID'] || -1;//or some other default` and then scroll to it:

```
var scrollOffset = 0, duration = 400;
var sectionElementId = "section" + $scope.sectionId; //you need to prefix the div id with "section" in this case or use just the SectionId
var sectionElement = angular.element(document.getElementById(sectionElementId));
$document.scrollToElement(sectionElement, scrollOffset, duration);
```